# how to pass array from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

i want to upload file in codeigniter and want to show error in view file but display error array is not displaying at view file. when uploading file is failed, relevant error is not display at view

```
function add_model()
{
    $this->checkuser();

    if(isset($_POST['add_model']))
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/model/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['file_name']  = rand(1111, 99999).'_'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        $config['overwrite']  = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name']  = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $mDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('model_name', 'Model Name', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('model_slug', 'Model Slug', 'trim|xss_clean|required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $temp = $this->upload->data('userfile');
            $model_image = $temp['file_name'];

            $data = array(
                    'model_name' => $this->input->post('model_name'),
                    'model_image' => $model_image,
                    'brand_id' => $this->input->post('brand_id'),
                    'model_slug' => $this->toAscii($this->input->post('model_slug'))
                    );

            $this->model_model->addmodel($data);
            redirect('admin/model/model_listing');
        }
        else
        {
            $data['errors'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $data['brands'] = $this->model_model->allbrand();
            $data['page_title'] = 'Add Content';
            $this->load->view('admin/add_model', $data);    
        }
    }
    else
    {
            $data['errors'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $data['brands'] = $this->model_model->allbrand();
            $data['page_title'] = 'Add Content';
            $this->load->view('admin/add_model', $data);        
    }


}
```

given below is the code of view file where i want to show error

```
<?php

    if(validation_errors())
    {
        echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-error">', '</div>');
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
    if($errors)
    {
         foreach ($errors as $error) 
         {
             echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.$error.'</div>';
         }
    }
?>
```

i am using both validation error and display error at the same time

Comment: And where is your "validation_errors()" error function? and the condition if true or false? Try reading this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

change this if condition

```
if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
```

to this

```
if($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload('name'))
        {
```

do_upload function requires name of field to upload image..